# Understanding java RMI exportObject method

Tags: java, rmi

I'm very new to RMI and I just decided to give it a try. I got confused by the `exportObject(Object, int)` method. The documentation says:

> Exports the remote object to make it available to receive incoming
>   calls, using the particular supplied port. **The object is exported with**
>   ***a server socket* created using the** `RMISocketFactory` **class**.

Consider the following simple example:

```
public interface Client extends Remote {
    void clientMethod() throws RemoteException;
}

public class ClientImpl implements Client {
    public clientMethod() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("clientMethod invoked");
    }
}

Client stub = (Client) UnicastRemoteObject
               .exportObject(new ClientImpl(), 56789); //<------ HERE
```

So we create a stub and will transfer it to another `VM` either manually or through `RmiRegistry`, doesn't matter here.

I'm confused by "[...] **the object is exported with a server socket** [...]"

What do they mean by that?

Comment: It means that the server-sided remote object will contain a server socket. Your `Client` stub holds a server socket at the server, and a client socket at the client. Your `Client` is a server unless it's a client.

Comment: With all seriousness now, do you understand Java's [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)? It listens to incoming TCP requests, and it's where RMI operates at the network level.

Comment: @E_net4 So, when we transfer the stub to another VM (VM 0), the stub will hold a socket connection to the VM (VM 2) it was originally created on. The VM 2 in trurn will maintain a server socket to accept incoming method invokations. Is that correct?

Comment: @E_net4 Your first sentence is correct. However your statement about the stub holding a server socket at the server is not. The stub doesn't hold any sockets at all anywhere.

Comment: @EJP Fair enough, I messed the nomenclatures up. It's been a while since I last used Java RMI and I just wanted to make a word play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A `ServerSocket` is created to listen for incoming connections at the port you specified when exporting. This port can be shared between multiple remote objects.
- The statement about the `RMISocketFactory` is incorrect. Where did you read that? This class has been obsolete since 1998.
- The stub contains the server's hostname or IP address and port number, and some internal data to identify the remote object it belongs to.
- TCP connections between the stub and the remote object are created on demand when you call remote methods, via a connection pool.

> So, when we transfer the stub to another VM (VM 0), the stub will hold a socket connection to the VM (VM 2) it was originally created on.

No, see above.

> The VM 2 in turn will maintain a server socket to accept incoming method invocations.

Correct.

Comment: I read it in the documentation. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject-java.rmi.Remote-int-